# Make CListView to close a div and open a new div after every fourth item in CListView

Tags: php, frameworks, yii

I am a beginner in Yii. I have a requirement in my hand to list all records in a model. So I am using view/MyModel/index.php to do the trick. I have used the following code for displaying them.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'template'=>'{pager}<br />{items}<br />{pager}<br />{summary}',
'itemView'=>'_view',
```

I am supposed to group every four records that I am displaying. So I will have to close a div tag after every fourth element and open a new div tag just after that.

Is there any means by which I can know the number of items rendered in the CListView so that I can close a div tag there and open a new one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($this->dataProvider->pagination) {
$data['realIndex']=$i+$this->dataProvider->pagination->currentPage*$this->dataProvider->pagination->pageSize;
} else {
$data['realIndex']=$i;
}
```

Extending the CListView class can get you the value of the current index of the item from the current page. That is if pagination is used each page will have the index of the item starting from 0.

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote this tutorial which gives a even better solution:

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/495/using-clistview-to-display-items-next-to-each-other-in-columns/

Comment: I had asked this question almost a year ago. I no more work in PHP nor do I work with the same company. I am sorry I cant test your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your "_itemView" file:

```
// your content

<?php if (($index+1) %4 == 0): ?></div><?php endif; ?>
```

That's it!